# Transferring non-operational vehicle title to new owner in different state

Tags: california, texas, motor-vehicle

I recently got married, and my new father in law gifted us a classic vehicle that needs a bit of repair to be operational. The vehicle is currently titled in California as a non-operational vehicle, but I live in Texas, specifically a county where registration depends on a safety and emissions check.  From what I can see a Texas title depends on the ability to register the vehicle, which cannot pass the county tests (due to non-operational status) to be registered.  I also cannot find where Texas may issue a similar non-operational title.  As a Texas resident, can I just simply transfer to a CA title with me as the owner, or must I title it in Texas if I intend to keep it here while repairing it? Is there a way to register and title in Texas without the car actually working?

Car is a 1967 Ford Bronco if that’s relevant.

Comment: Not to be rude about it, but if Texas won't let you register a non working vehicle then it should be self explanatory that you can't register it. Fix the car then register it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not making the actual question clear. I need to fix the car. I live in TX. Therefore I have to work on it in TX. But I can't register it in TX unless I'm reading the rules wrong. A bit of a catch 22 situation unless there's a legal way to maneuver around it or I'm perhaps reading the statutes wrong. Hence why I'm here.

Comment: Once again. You are not able to register it in TX until it is fixed right? So fix it then register it.

Comment: But a car titled in Texas owned by a resident of Texas must be registered in Texas. That's the dilemma. I can't register it until it's fixed, but I can't fix it until it's here, at which point it must be registered. Unless I'm reading the statutes wrong.

Comment: Listen dude, what you are saying does not make sense. They specifically told you that you can not register it until it is operational. Work on the car, then register it. They told you that.

Comment: The question is about transferring of ownership, of which registering is only a part. The current owner is a CA resident. I'm in TX. As I'm reading the laws of TX, if I take ownership I must register it immediately, which I can't unless it's working. I can't imagine that this is the first instance of a car not working being acquired by someone as a hobby car to work on. All I'm asking is how to go about the paperwork to make this happen. The legalese behind this is confusing at best so I'm trying to reach out to people who've done this before and can offer advice.

Comment: Ok dude, registering it immediately does not apply to a car that can't pass the test or there would be no test.

Comment: For the Nth time, they want you to fix it before you register it. So fix it then register it.

Comment: Can you link to something that validates that in TX code? Because I've looked for weeks and found nothing to make this an exception.

Comment: Also, can't title it until registering. Meaning CA title remains. Meaning I don't own it?

Comment: You would own a hunk of metal. It's just like the TV show American Pickers where they buy the frame of a car or something then fix it and **then** register it.

Comment: It does not have to be registered if you are not going to operate it on a roadway. You can put it in your name in CA if you want, but as far as TX goes, they are going to require you to make it pass their test before you register and title it.

Comment: Ok that's an answer that helps. So you're saying that I can title in my name in CA even though I live in TX? I haven't found anything to support that on the CA websites, so that's why I'm here. Hoping to get some guidance on which path to pursue.

Comment: Why not just wait until it gets to be operational? I don't understand why you aren't just taking that path.

Comment: Becoming operational is based on my working on it for months or years. I need to transfer ownership now.

Comment: You don't need to register it and all that if it is not derivable though. Registering just means you are certified to operate on TX roadways. It does not affect anything if the car is not working. It doesn't hamper anything if you wait.

Comment: So can I get a TX title without having to register? That's the main confusion I'm having. Everything I've seen wants me to do both at once.

Comment: No lol. I don't want to be rude, but I just don't know of any other way to say it. You don't do either in TX to a car that is not working.

Comment: There isn't a reason to. If you got a title or registered a non working car in TX it wouldn't mean anything. Getting those things allows your car to be driven on the road in TX. It does nothing for a car that can't drive.

Comment: It means something for transference of ownership, which is the main crux of the question.

Comment: It doesn't bc its not a freaking car until its working. You just own a hunk of metal. If I sell you 3k pounds of steel you own it whether the state of TX gives you a paper or not.

Comment: Ok seriously? There's a title on this car. In California. For a person not myself. Therefore California says this car belongs to someone else. Regardless of whether I give them money, that title means it's not mine until they sign it over. At which point I need a CA title or TX title. That's the question. Which one is legal for me to pursue and how do I go about it.

Comment: TX has told you that TX titles don't exist for non working cars. Do whatever you would like in CA, but it has no bearing on what TX does. In TX that is just metal until you fix it.

Comment: TX has told me nothing. You keep inferring that I've gotten advice elsewhere but I never stated that. My claim was based on some research I've done, but I'm not a legal expert. You're also not saying whether California would allow me to title there. Not to be rude, but nothing you are saying seems like sound legal advice or even informed knowledge on the topic. You seem to just be offering "try this" with no regard for the consequences or legality of what you're suggesting. When I asked for specific evidence to back up your claims, you offered nothing. Expected more from this forum.

Comment: The research you have done is the advice. You saw that you need an inspection did you not?

Comment: What you own is not a motor vehicle until it passes inspection.

Comment: Transportation Code Section 501.030
(a) Before a motor vehicle that was last registered or titled in another state or
country may be titled in this state, the county assessor-collector shall verify that
the vehicle has passed the inspections required by Chapter 548, as indicated in
the Department of Public Safety's inspection database under Section 548.251,
or that the owner has obtained an identification number inspection in
accordance with department rule.

Comment: As your own research and I have told you, you may not title it in Texas until you get it running. If you expect more of this site, you expect me to fly to TX and change TX law.

Comment: Titling a car meaning registering it under your name refers to a working automobile. It does not mean you own or do not own a non driveable piece of metal.

Comment: Please be respectful and listen when you ask for advice here.

Comment: @JBrown  Form 130 does have an option to transfer title without registering it. I think you need to have an inspection to verify the VIN ("ID number inspection") or maybe that's only if there is no existing title. Seriously, go to the DMV and ask them.

Comment: @mkennedy please read the law I cited. It says out of state vehicles must pass the inspection. His can not.

Answer (score -1):

They have told you that you can not register the vehicle until it is operational.  You ,yourself, acknowledge that you must be able to pass inspection in your question

> but I live in Texas, specifically a county where registration depends on a safety and emissions check.

You work on the car and get it to the point where it passes their inspection.
**After you do that,** you register the vehicle in Texas. If it takes you years to finish the car, you register it in years.

A title on a nonworking vehicle would do nothing, because the car can't drive down the road. A police officer can't stop a non-operational vehicle and demand to see it's registration.

Texas law states you must have a vehicle that will pass the inspection to get the title in your case:

> Transportation Code Section 501.030 (a) Before a motor vehicle that was last registered or titled in another state or country may be titled in this state, the county assessor-collector shall verify that the vehicle has passed the inspections required by Chapter 548, as indicated in the Department of Public Safety's inspection database under Section 548.251, or that the owner has obtained an identification number inspection in accordance with department rule.

Not having a Texas title does not mean you do not own it. It means it is not considered a motor vehicle by the state. You still own it as you would own any other piece of metal you own. If you bought the car or it was given to you, you own it with or without a Texas title.

With or without the title someone wanting to take it would have to go to court and you could tell the court you own it and provide whatever proof you have either way, which is how it is intended to be done.